# OSGi application design and DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, osgi, ddd-repositories

After reading [OSGi application design - am I abusing the service framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469690/osgi-application-design-am-i-abusing-the-service-framework) and [What is the best way of grouping OSGi bundles to make a coherent 'application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326143/what-is-the-best-way-of-grouping-osgi-bundles-to-make-a-coherent-application), I'm now stuck with burning question of how to apply the "don't program OSGi" mantra.

Assuming the bounded context is the entire application and not the individual bundles, I should be free to declare some aggregate root entity in an API bundle, and in the DDD style, a repository for working with said entity. Now, the crux of the matter: an explicit repository appears to be antithetical to the OSGi style because a repository is itself a registry (of domain objects), and this design sidesteps the OSGi service registry. But to do away with the repository would require consumers to program OSGi in order to perform lookups of an entity.

It is said that repositories are just a façade--does this imply that I should create a repository implementation which delegates to the service registry? This does not appear to be a coherent approach since consumers would have two entry points into the domain model: the repository, and the service registry itself. To forgo the repository would no longer be DDD because we're back to mixing domain logic with framework code in a spaghetti-like fashion.

So what's the take-away here? Is domain-driven design incompatible with the "OSGi way," or am I missing some critical concept?

Comment: Are you aware of Declarative Services? They allow you to consume OSGi-services without a dependency on any OSGi-API.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Declarative approaches to avoid dependencies have a limitation: they are static. This means I cannot add an entity to the service registry on the fly (e.g. when a customer places an order) using this approach alone. A domain-specific repository, on the other hand, is dynamic in nature--this allows complete entity lifecycle management.

Comment: Actually you can do this on the fly - the service component runtime can create new instances of service components when new configurations are registered with the configuration admin (and will remove them when you remove the configuration). There are usecases when you should manage the lifecycle of services manually (for instance when service represents a networked device that may become unavailable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale for not depending on OSGi is that as middleware OSGi visibility in your code makes it less cohesive. Domain code and OSGi code should not mix (just like it should not mix with JMS, Java EE, or any other API). Less cohesive code is more complicated and therefore error prone.

However, you always need some bridging code that links the infra-structure to your domain code. Since this bridging code is going to be coupled to some API anyway, leverage it to the hilt, there is absolutely no use in abstracting yourself from the environment for bridge code.

DS (and Blueprint, iPOJO, etc) hide the registry for the business logic, they are just very convenient ways to provide your domain registry. So with OSGi you hardly have to write any code to have a very powerful repository of domain objects without your domain objects themselves being aware of OSGi.

Yes, if you move your code from OSGi to somewhere else you have to rewrite the bridge code and coming from an OSGi world writing the generic functionality provided by OSGi is surprisingly large. However, not using the OSGi constructs because in event that the app is ported you have to provide is functionality is throwing away money.

Conclusion: domain could should not mix with OSGi, bridge code should leverage OSGi to the hilt.

Comment: Upon further reflection, the corollary question is whether or not domain objects qualify as services in the OSGi sense. In the book "OSGi In Depth," there is an example involving auctions where each Auction instance is directly accessed via the service registry. So far this is the only example I've seen which encourages such usage.

Comment: What I find unsettling is that domain objects (particularly entities) are largely defined by their **identity**, which appears to imply that one cannot arbitrarily substitute one for another as one would with services. Sure, filters can help narrow down which service is retrieved from the registry, but with domain objects the degree to which narrowing down is required will typically boil down to a specific ID. Is always selecting an exact service an acceptable use of the registry, or is this abuse?

Comment: As always it depends ... In general the driving force should be does it work with the least amount of work without causing severe road blocks later down the line. If you have potentially thousands of domain objects, the registry will not scale (though I've heard of systems with 60.000 services ...). I would get started with services and see how it goes, when the domain objects and the domain logic are not aware of OSGi, adding another infrastructure layer should not be that hard ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply register the repository as an OSGi service. The bundles that need the repository should reference the service and should only know of the repository interface. Of course this means you have to use either a ServiceTracker in an Activator or e.g. a blueprint context. I prefer the blueprint context as this way you do not have a real java level dependency on OSGi.

Of course this creates a dependency to OSGi in some way but this is not avoidable. The basic idea to follow is that you should keep the OSGi specific code out of your business code and have it in separate classes or in blueprint.

See one of my tutorials which shows a simple application with  UI, a model and a persistence impl. While the application is too small to really do DDD the aproach should be fairly compatible. One thing you will notice is that the whole application does not import a single OSGi interface. One nice side effect is that you can easily reuse the code outside OSGi but then of course you have to solve the DI differently.

http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/DIBZ